# How to add a protected custom setting to a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, customsetting

I have a managed package that I've created, I would like to add another custom settings object into there. However, this object is no where to be seen when I click on the add button.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have been added automatically. Salesforce performs a dependency check and automatically includes custom settings, fields, objects, classes, pages, components, labels, static resources, and so on as necessary. Check the list of included items to make sure it has not already been added to the package.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Also, there must be no data within the custom setting before you can add it to the package.